# Combining two 8-Bit array to a USHORT (16 Bit) , without loop

Tags: c++, c

I need to combine two `UCHAR` (8 Bit) arrays to a `USHORT` (16 Bit) value in C. But I must do that without using "for" or any loop.

as:

```
UCHAR A[1000], B[1000];
USHORT C[1000];
```

result must be as:

```
C[0] = {A[0], B[0]};
C[1] = {A[1], B[1]};
...
C[1000]={A[1000], B[1000]};
```

Comment: What do you mean by "combine"?

Comment: Two questions: 1. What is the endian-ness of your processor?  2. Which of the two UCHARs is the Least Significant Byte and which one is the Most Significant Byte?  So if auch[2] = {0x00, 0xFF} do you expect a USHORT value of 255 or 4080 (16 x 255)?

Comment: Edit your question and describe it in more detail what is the input and what kind of output you expect.

Comment: if a[0]=0x01 and b[0]=0x23 then C[0]= 0x2301

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
uint8_t one = 0xBA;
uint8_t two = 0xBE;

uint16_t both = one << 8 | two;
```

**UPDATE:** 
Maybe I have not understood your problem... but if you want to convert a uint8_t array to a uint16_t array-> check size and cast

```
uint8_t array[100];
uint16_t array_ptr_ushort* =(uint16_t*)&array[0];
```

Make sure the size of the array is even.

**UPDATE2:**

```
uint8_t array1[100];
uint8_t array2[100];
uint16_t combined[100];

memcpy(combined, array1, sizeof(array1))
memcpy((uint8_t*)combined + sizeof(array1), array2, sizeof(array2))
```

**UPDATE3:**

You can not combine two arrays in one contignous array without some sort of loop, the loop will exist in the underlying hardware even you use DMA for this...

**UPDATE4:**

You can do it recursively.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <cstdint>
#include <algorithm>

uint8_t arrayA[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
uint8_t arrayB[] = {0xA, 0x9, 0x8, 0x7, 0x6, 0x5, 0x4, 0x3, 0x2, 0x1};
uint16_t array_combined[sizeof(arrayA)] = {};
static_assert(sizeof(arrayA) == sizeof(arrayB), "Arrays of different sizes");

uint16_t combine(const uint8_t *a, const uint8_t *b, uint16_t *put, uint32_t size)
{
    uint16_t value = (*a << 8) | *b;
    if(size)
        *put = combine(++a, ++b, ++put, --size);
    return value;
}

void combine_arrays(const uint8_t *a, const uint8_t *b, uint16_t *put, uint32_t size)
{
    *put = combine(a, b, put, size);
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    combine_arrays(arrayA, arrayB, array_combined, sizeof(arrayA));

return 0;
}
```

**UPDATE5:** C version with static_assert from C++

```
#include <stdint.h>


uint8_t array1[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
uint8_t array2[] = {0xA, 0x9, 0x8, 0x7, 0x6, 0x5, 0x4, 0x3, 0x2, 0x1};
uint16_t array_combined[sizeof(array1)] = {};
static_assert(sizeof(array1) == sizeof(array2), "Arrays of different sizes");

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    int size = sizeof(array1);
    int count = 0;
    do
    {
        array_combined[count] = (array2[count] << 8) | array1[count];
    }while(count++ != size);

    return 0;
}
```

**UPDATE6:** There are also C++ ways to achieve this...

Comment: memcpy or other similar funcs, copying one by one :( ; if there was an different func that be able to copy only odds, it being solve :( . Is there any solution ?

Comment: @user2087181 is this enough?

Comment: can u check my idea ?  >> if i create a struct, that contain Two UCHAR;  as struct USHORT_VAL
  {
   UCHAR LOW;  // byte 0
   UCHAR HIGH;  // byte 1
  } sUSHORT_VAL;                                                                                  then , Can I copy as memcpy(sUSHORTval[].LOW,array1, sizeof(array1)) ? ??????????????

Comment: @user2087181, your example will not work, I have added also the recursive version... a struct is continous memory... you can not copy-with-gaps using memcpy...

Comment: you can use union structur with two type definiation, uchar (lsb and msb) and uint.

Answer (score 2):

```
ushortVal = ( ucharVal[0] << 8 ) | ucharVal[1];
```

Comment: you apear to be missing a ( there.

Comment: @Oren:  Thanks!  You are correct.  Eyeball compiler working poorly.

Comment: Is `<< 8` getting the MSB?

Comment: @David: Assuming they are unsigned as stated in the OP it will.

Answer (score 2):

For single element, you can just **shift** first byte **bitwise to the left** by 8 bits and add the second byte by using **bitwise or**:

```
C[i] = (A[i] << 8) | B[i];
```

But for arrays, you basically want to "scatter" two arrays into the third array like this:

```
A[0] B[0]  |  A[1] B[1]  |  A[2] B[2]  |  ...  |  A[n-1] B[n-1]

   C[0]    |     C[1]    |     C[2]    |  ...  |     C[n-1]
```

which means that if the first element of the array `C` is stored at the address `0`, then elements from the array `A` should be at addresses 0, 16, 32, 48... and elements from the array `B` at addresses 8, 24, ...
which IMHO **can not be done without using any loop**

Comment: that's a single operation, but I have two 8-bit arrays ! :(

Comment: @user2087181 Would you please edit your question to be clearer? What are the inputs and the desired output? From its current wording, you're trying to combine two arrays of UCHARs into one value of USHORT.